# Speed up query table temporaly

Tags: mysql, date, count

I need to speed up a query in mysql that takes 45 seconds, I need to count for months / years including the months that there are no results in the table, for that I create a temporary table of dates and then I launch the following query, how can I speed it up?

```
//CREATE TABLE OF DATES AND INSERT
CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE fechas(fecha date);

INSERT INTO fechas(fecha)
        select * from 
        (select adddate("1970-01-01",t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date between "2017-01-01" and "2018-01-01" 
    order by selected_date;
```

//QUERY

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha, "%m-%Y") as data, 
        ifnull((
            SELECT ifnull(COUNT(*),0) 
            FROM cupons c 
            WHERE YEAR(c.dataCupo) = YEAR(f.fecha) 
            AND MONTH(c.dataCupo) = MONTH(f.fecha)  
            and c.empresa=1 
            AND c.proveidor!="VINCULADO"
            group by YEAR(c.dataCupo), MONTH(c.dataCupo)
            ORDER BY c.dataCupo
        ),0)  AS num 
FROM fechas f 
where f.fecha BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2018-01-01" 
GROUP BY YEAR(f.fecha),MONTH(f.fecha);
```

//Result:

**data    | num**

01-2018 | 15

02-2018 | 0

03-2018 | 20

04-2018 | 0

....

Comment: Side note `select adddate("1970-01-01"` .... `selected_date between "2017-01-01"` when don't you change `1970-01-01` into `2017-01-01` because `2017-01-01` is your start date and not `1970-01-01`

Comment: Why don't you simple build a static calendar table with proper indexes ?

Comment: Provide the output off `EXPLAIN [query]` so we can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping columns in functions is going to prevent MySQL from making effective use of an index.

```
WHERE YEAR(c.dataCupo) = ... 
  AND MONTH(c.dataCupo) = ...
```

Here's a pattern that allows MySQL to use a range scan operation on an appropriate index

```
WHERE c.dataCupo >=  ... 
  AND c.dataCupo <   ...
```

The correlated subquery in the SELECT list is going to get executed multiple times. If we are going to go that route, then it would be much better to get the grouping of `fechas` done FIRST, and then execute the subquery for each month, cuts down on the number of executions.

But I wouldn't do that, I would use an outer join operation.

And I would get only get one row per month from `fechas`, and get the corresponding counts by month, rather than getting them by day.

With no change to the temporary table, then something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha, "%m-%Y")  AS data
     , COUNT(c.dataCupo)              AS num
  FROM fechas f
  LEFT
  JOIN cupons c 
    ON c.dataCupo  >= f.fecha
   AND c.dataCuop   < f.fecha + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND c.empresa    = 1
   AND c.proveidor != 'VINCULADO'
 WHERE f.fecha >= '2017-01-01'
   AND f.fecha  < '2018-01-01'
   AND DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha,'%d') = '01'
 GROUP 
    BY f.fecha
```

Note the condition `DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha,'%d') = '01'` is getting us just the first day of the month. It looks like populating the temporary table gets us unique date values, so we won't get duplicates.

Comment: year(c.dataCupo)=year(f.fecha) and .... its for join the table of info(cupons) and the table of dates(fechas)

Comment: @RaymondNijland: by "effective use" I meant a range scan operation, rather than a full scan. MySQL can do a full index scan... my point is that wrapping that column in a function makes MySQL evaluate that function for every row in the table. And with OP query, MySQL is doing a full scan of the `cupons` table for each of the 365 days returned from fechas. It's much more efficient to use a range scan for each individual day... assuming an even distribution of date values, the range scan for a single n each execution quickly eliminating 99.7% of the rows from consideration.

Comment: "by "effective use" I meant a range scan operation, rather than a full scan." Ok that indeed makes sense a range scan is indeed (much) faster then a full index scan.